# Advantages of using [ClassInitilize]Attribute over static Constructor (or: TestContext wat?!)

Tags: c#, mstest

---

I do not get the benefits of the `[ClassInitilize]` Attribute.

---

### Example code

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    static MyTestClass()
    {
        //startup logic
    }

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Initilize(TestContext context)
    {
        //startup logic
    }
}
```

### **Question**

Is there any real world usage of using `[ClassInitilize]` over a static constructor?
I mean i get that in the `Initilize()` Method you get a `TestContext` object but I don't really see any use for it.

*In short:*
**What does one need `TestContext` for.**

Comment: The `TestContext` is useful for example for [data driven tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx). And you can [write to the test output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.writeline.aspx). For more use cases, start at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.aspx)

Comment: [Using the `TestContext` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms404699(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: I don't know why I didn't manage to find the last link.. Must have lost my googleforce, it never popped up :o  Thank you @RenéVogt

Comment: It was mentioned at the documentation site I linked above, but without a link, I then googled for "inurl:msdn Using the TestContext Class"...

Comment: What hackery ;)

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN: Using the `TestContext` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404699(v=vs.80).aspx):

> You use the TestContext class in unit tests for any of several purposes. These are its most frequent uses:
>
> - In any unit test, because the TestContext class stores information that is provided to unit tests, such as the path to the deployment directory. For more information, see [Structure of Unit Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517(v=vs.80).aspx).
> - In unit tests to test Web services that run on ASP.NET Development Server. In this case, TestContext stores the URL of the Web service. For more information, see [Testing Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243399(v=vs.80).aspx).
> - In ASP.NET unit tests, to obtain access to the Page object. For more information, see [Working with ASP.NET Unit Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404696(v=vs.80).aspx).
> - In data-driven unit tests, the TestContext class is required because it provides access to the data row. For more information, see [Working with Data-Driven Unit Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404708(v=vs.80).aspx), [Coding a Data-Driven Unit Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527(v=vs.80).aspx), and [Walkthrough: Using a Configuration File to Define a Data Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243192(v=vs.80).aspx).